# Get script absapth executed by Django shell

Tags: python, django, path

I have a script called myscript.py and I try to print the file path in it.

```
print(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

I executed the script using django shell

```
./manage.py shell < myscript.py
```

However, I could not get the script file path but the shell.py file path. what I get is something like:

...lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.py

Why abspath(**file**) does not show myscript.py path? is there a way to print out the path of myscript.py? Thanks

Comment: import your script in shell as `import myscript`

Comment: or you can simply run, `python myscript.py`

Comment: @ArakkalAbu Thanks i know that when i execute the script with python cmd i can get the path, but I do need the django shell to execute my script because I have to use django settings in the script.

Comment: You can run standalone django script though